# Is Linux caching RAs?

Tags: linux, networking, arch-linux, ipv6

Due to [a bug in OpenBSD rtadvd](https://marc.info/?l=openbsd-misc&m=152828623709937&w=2), my router sometimes sends RA with an incorrect prefix

```
prefix 2001:41d0:fe4b:ecf1::/64
prefix 2001:41d0:fe4b:ec42::/64
prefix 2a01:e35:8aea:ac42::/64
```

But if I fix it so it only sends the correct prefixes (`2001:41d0:fe4b:ec42::/64` and `prefix 2a01:e35:8aea:ac42::/64`), and **delete the address** from the interface, my Linux box keeps assigning IPv6 from the erroneous prefix each time it gets a RA from the router.

```
15:46:44.138257 IP6 (hlim 255, next-header ICMPv6 (58) payload length: 136) fe80::8621:df60:6d70:8da > ff02::1: [icmp6 sum ok] ICMP6, router advertisement, length 136
    hop limit 64, Flags [none], pref medium, router lifetime 1800s, reachable time 0s, retrans time 0s
      source link-address option (1), length 8 (1): 00:00:24:d1:42:0d
        0x0000:  0000 24d1 420d
      prefix info option (3), length 32 (4): 2a01:e35:8aea:ac42::/64, Flags [onlink, auto], valid time 2592000s, pref. time 604800s
        0x0000:  40c0 0027 8d00 0009 3a80 0000 0000 2a01
        0x0010:  0e35 8aea ac42 0000 0000 0000 0000
      prefix info option (3), length 32 (4): 2001:41d0:fe4b:ec42::/64, Flags [onlink, auto], valid time 2592000s, pref. time 604800s
        0x0000:  40c0 0027 8d00 0009 3a80 0000 0000 2001
        0x0010:  41d0 fe4b ec42 0000 0000 0000 0000
      rdnss option (25), length 24 (3):  lifetime 900s, addr: 2a01:e35:8aea:ac42::10
        0x0000:  0000 0000 0384 2a01 0e35 8aea ac42 0000
        0x0010:  0000 0000 0010
      dnssl option (31), length 24 (3):  lifetime 900s, domain(s): geekwu.org.
        0x0000:  0000 0000 0384 0667 6565 6b77 7503 6f72
        0x0010:  6700 0000 0000
15:46:44.553069 IP6 (hlim 255, next-header ICMPv6 (58) payload length: 32) :: > ff02::1:ffd1:28d4: [icmp6 sum ok] ICMP6, neighbor solicitation, length 32, who has 2001:41d0:fe4b:ecf1:8581:1b57:b9d1:28d4
      unknown option (14), length 8 (1): 
        0x0000:  1d76 c406 8db8
```

You can see the RA with only 2 prefixes, and then the `neighbor solicitation` packet, which is my box checking it the address is "free" (DAD) ... and it is, as this prefix is not in use on this ethernet link.
As this address is the last inserted, it's the default one for outgoing connections, but the router cannot route it back, as it's not defined.

I can only guess the kernel -- or something in userland -- is keeping the old RA in cache, for whatever reason, and uses it instead of the "live" RA (or maybe it merges them ?)

If so, is there any way to see it ? to flush or alter this cache ? I can probably rebbot my box, but, well ... seems bad.

(kernel 4.16.13-1-ARCH)

EDIT:

I sent a RA with scapy for this prefix, with 0 lifetime, and the address stops beeing added for each subsequent RA.

```
Welcome to Scapy (unknown.version)
>>> a = IPv6()
>>> a.dst = "ff02::1"
>>> b = ICMPv6ND_RA()
>>> b.display()
>>> c = ICMPv6NDOptSrcLLAddr()
>>> c.lladdr = "00:00:24:d1:42:0d"
>>> d = ICMPv6NDOptMTU()
>>> e = ICMPv6NDOptPrefixInfo()
>>> e.prefixlen = 64
>>> e.prefix = "2001:41d0:fe4b:ecf1::"
>>> e.preferredlifetime=0
>>> e.validlifetime=0
>>> send(a/b/c/d/e)
```

NetworkManager (1.10.8) is running on this box, with default configuration

Comment: What SLAAC client are you using – dhcpcd, NetworkManager, networkd, or the kernel itself?

Comment: Have you tried explicitly withdrawing the prefix (advertising with valid 0, preferred 0, etc.)?

Comment: NetworkManager is running, but I don't know if it's the SLAAC client. sending withdrawing RA removes the address for good

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like the expected result.

SLAAC allows multiple routers to advertise different sets of prefixes, therefore new RAs *do not* invalidate previous ones, only update them incrementally.

Once a prefix has been configured, it remains for the duration of its "valid" lifetime (refreshed by each new RA), unless a RA *explicitly* sets the lifetime of that prefix to zero. (See [RFC 4862](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4862#section-5.5.3).)

Comment: even if you delete the assigned address ?

Comment: RFC says "For each Prefix-Information option in the Router Advertisement:" not "For each Prefix-Information option in the Router Advertisement we ever received"